# Xamarin Forms Android app fails on launch: Can't detect when [class] is activated/deactivated..implement IActivationForViewFetcher

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, reactiveui

As the title says this is the error from the device log when launching a Xamarin forms android app in release mode on Android Q. This occurs on a release device only.
System.ArgumentException: Don't know how to detect when [launcher class] is activated/deactivated, you may need to implement IActivationForViewFetcher

Any ideas why? 
My linker settings are shown in the image: 
[image: Linker settings]

Comment: This will be fixed by a bug fix release today. See https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/2256